# Why is 'import simplejson' failing in Python 2.7.3 code, but not in the interpreter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, simplejson

There are two instances running uwgsi and nginx servers.  Each hosts a Flask application.  Both are running on a Python 2.7.3 path. One of the servers throws an ImportError for the "import simplejson" statement.  The interpreter on both servers will accept this import statement without complaint.

Here's the source of application A:

```
  1 from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, views                                                                                                   
  2 import sys
  3 print sys.version
  4 print sys.path
  5 
  6 import os
  7 import functools
  8 import urllib,urllib2
  9 import simplejson
 10 from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

And the source of application B:

```
  1 from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, abort, render_template, flash, views                                                                                                   
  2 
  3 import sys
  4 print sys.version          
  5 print sys.path             
  6 
  7 import simplejson  
  8 
  9 import functools
```

Here's the sys.version and sys.path log output of server A:

```
2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:25:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
['/srv/www/A/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',     
'/srv/www/A/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
'/srv/www/A/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', 
'/srv/www/A/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/srv/www/A/env/lib/python2.7', 
'/srv/www/A/20120910/src', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/srv/www/A/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/srv/www/A/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='notimportant.com|') ready in 1 seconds on interpreter 0x1b20420 pid: 11069
```

Here's the sys.version and sys.path log output of server B:

```
2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:25:23) 
[GCC 4.6.3]
['/srv/www/B/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', 
'/srv/www/B/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/srv/www/B/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg', 
'/srv/www/B/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg', 
'/srv/www/B/env/lib/python2.7', 
'/srv/www/B/20130105/src', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', 
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', 
'/srv/www/B/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/srv/www/B/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/www/B/20130105/src/B.py", line 7, in <module>
    import simplejson
ImportError: No module named simplejson
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='notimportant.com|') (callable not found or import error)
```

Any constructive ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: On python 2.7, just `import json` will do; it's the same module, but bundled with Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`simplejson` is an external library; it is bundled with Python 2.6 and up as the [`json` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Just use `import json` instead of `import simplejson`, *or* install `simplejson` on server B too.

If you replace your `simplejson` import with `json`, remember to fix any references in the file. Alternatively, import it like this:

```
try:
    import simplejson
except ImportError:
    import json as simplejson
```

and it'll use the stdlib `json` module, renamed, and all your references to `simplejson` will continue to work.

Comment: Of course, you'll need to change any statements where you use `simplejson` to use `json` instead:  e.g. `simplejson.load` -> `json.load`.  Alternatively, `import json as simplejson`, but that last one should be considered a temporary hack at best.

Comment: Frankly, I got the relationship between json and simplejson reversed in my mind.  I thought json was external and simplejson internal to Py2.6+. I also fixed the problem by sourcing my virtualenv and typing "pip install simplejson"...  THANK YOU ALL.